# Complete separation of logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression

I came over problem that might occur in logistic regression. In case dataset is too small to observe events with low probabilities. For example, in the following table we have response set to 0 if $X\le5$ and 1 is $X>5$, so we have **complete separation problem below**. The predictors are $X$, so since our predictors is large, it's more likely to have complete separation.

[image]

**Question**: I don't see how this correlation is true between size of dataset being small to observe events with low probabilities and complete separation. If we are to find the parameters $\theta$ that maximize the probability of getting our dataset $D$ for logistic regression:

$$
\theta _{MLE}=\underset{\theta \in \Theta}{arg\max}\ p\left( D|\theta \right) 
$$

Then with complete separation in place, it hinders the convergence of MLE. So I am not sure how to connect MLE, data size being small and complete separation together?